# Bootstrap file input plugin maximageheight and maximagewidth not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, file, input

I've set the maxImageWidth and maxImageHeight to 50 yet i can still upload images with dimensions bigger than the given ones here.What could be the problem?

```
<script>

        $("#files").fileinput({
        language: 'en',
        uploadUrl: "Upload.php",
        previewFileIcon: '<i class="fa fa-file"></i>',
        initialCaption: "Images", 
        uploadAsync: false,
        minFileCount: 0,
        maxFileCount: 5,
        maxImageWidth: 50, 
        maxImageHeight: 50,
        maxFileSize: 10000,
        showPreview: true,
        validateInitialCount: true,
        overwriteInitial: false,
        showUpload: false, 
        showRemove: false,
        allowedFileExtensions: ["jpg","jpeg","JPG","JPEG"],
        allowedPreviewMimeTypes: ['image/jpg','image/jpeg','image/JPG','image/JPEG'],
        initialPreview: [
        <?php foreach($images as $image){?>
            "<img src='<?php echo $image; ?>' height='120px' class='file-preview-image'>",
        <?php } ?>],
        initialPreviewConfig: [<?php foreach($images as $image){ $infoImages=explode("/",$image);?>
        {caption: "<?php echo $infoImages[1];?>",  height: "120px", url: "Delete.php", key:"<?php echo $infoImages[1];?>"},
        <?php } ?>]
        }).on("filebatchselected", function(event, files) {

        $("#files").fileinput("upload");

        });

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must download the new versionos of Fileinput script

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).